# Javascript's "new Date()" returns different dates for '2011-02-1' and '2011-02-01'

Tags: javascript, date

Here's my experiment:

```
> new Date('2011-02-1')
2011-02-01T08:00:00.000Z
> new Date('2011-02-01')
2011-02-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

Does anybody know why there are 8 hours difference between the two?

Thanks!

Comment: Interestingly enough, where I am (Eastern US) the difference is actually 5 hours, not 8.  If you're on the West Coast of the US, I'm gonna bet it has something to do with a bug in the time zone logic.

Comment: Actually, I'm curious, what browser are you using?

Comment: Better yet, are you saying if you run those one after the other in your browser you get a different result?

Comment: I was using node v10.12.0

Comment: @str Holy cow, that's a nice exhaustive answer. I'll VTC as well for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually up to the browser or JavaScript runtime implementation to determine what happens. The `Date` constructor conforms to the format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` which is a simplification of ISO 8601 Extended Format. If parsing that fails, it is **implementation-specific** what happens.

Essentially, since you failed to specify `DD` for `2011-02-1`, it's up to the browser to call the shots on what you'll get. For example, in Google Chrome and Firefox I get `2011-02-01T00:00:00.000Z` yet in Safari I just get an error, `Invalid Date`.

See [the ECMAScript 5 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2):

> […] the value produced by `Date.parse` is implementation-dependent when given any String value that does not conform to the Date Time String Format ([15.9.1.15](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)) and that could not be produced in that implementation by the `toString` or `toUTCString` method.

Note that the `Date` constructor uses the same parsing algorithm as `Date.parse`. This is why it's highly discouraged to use a string for the constructor. Use the multi-argument version that is standardized. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax).